# Converting a double to an std::bitset

Tags: c++11

I have a `double` that I would like to convert to an `std::bitset<64>`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the pointer to the double variable to unsigned long long, derefence it again and use that as argument for the constructor

```
double d = 0;    
std::bitset<64> b(*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(&d)))
```

But that's not very beautiful.

Here is a approach with a union:

```
union DoubleToLongLong {
    double d;
    long long ll;
};

...
DoubleToLongLong dtll;
dtll.d = 3.4;
std::bitset<64> b(dtll.ll);
...
```

And because `unions` can have constructors also this is possible:

```
union DoubleToLongLong {
    double d;
    long long ll;
    DoubleToLongLong(double _d) : d(_d) {}
};

...
std::bitset<64> b(DoubleToLongLong(3.4).ll);
...
```

Comment: Is this snippet a source of undefined behavior?
`DoubleToLongLong dtll;
dtll.d = 3.4;
std::bitset<64> b(dtll.ll);`

I thought that if you were to use a union, you should only access the member of the same type that was assigned. That is, you should not be accessing dtll.ll, because the member `ll` was not assigned, it was the member `d` that was assigned.

Comment: No it isn't. This is totally valid to do and one of the main use cases of an union. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7666195/2531813

Answer (score 0):

```
constexpr auto BITS = sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT;

std::bitset<BITS> to_bitset(double d) {
    auto bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&d);

    std::bitset<BITS> bits;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(d); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT; ++j) {
            bits[i * CHAR_BIT + j] = (bytes[i] >> j) & 1;
        }
    }
    return bits;
}
```